# I have a problem with assignment related to Transform

Tags: css, transform

The div::after element which is behind the div::before element is supposed to appear after hovering over the parent  element, but the problem is that the div::after element appears in reverse, so where did I go wrong?

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #FA3664;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
div:hover {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
div::before {
    content: "Front";
    color: white;
    background-color: #FA3664;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
div::after {
    content: "Back";
    color: white;
    background-color: #1692FC;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to rotate the back face

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FA3664;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

div:hover {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

div::before {
  content: "Front";
  color: white;
  background-color: #FA3664;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

div::after {
  content: "Back";
  color: white;
  background-color: #1692FC;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg); /* added */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, Everything is fine now, but, why do we need to rotate back-face?

Comment: because you are rotating the parent element that will affect the back element, so you need to perform another rotation to have in the good direction

Answer (score 0):

Because the div is rotated so are the pseudo elements, so the back (after) gets a rotation of -180deg. If you build in the same type of rotation to the after pseudo element it will appear the right way round.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FA3664;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

div:hover {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

div::before {
  content: "Front";
  color: white;
  background-color: #FA3664;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

div::after {
  content: "Back";
  color: white;
  background-color: #1692FC;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Note however that you have more subtle problem - unless the user hovers centrally the card can flip from pink to blue and back again several times. This is because the hover state comes and goes - as the card rotates. You may like to put a container div around the div and pick up the hover on that and rotate the child div only to give a more stable experience.